# trying to pivot data from columns to rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take this data:

| groupid | sessnum | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 0 | notes overview |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 1 | note s1 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 2 | note s2 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 3 | note s3 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 4 | note s4 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 5 | note s5 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 6 | note s6 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 7 | note s7 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 8 | note s8 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 9 | note s9 |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | 10 | note s10 |

What I want to get is

| groupid | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 | S6 | S7 | S8 | S9 | S10 | OVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | note s1 | note s2 | note s3 | note s4 | note s5 | note s6 | note s7 | note s8 | note s9 | note s10 | notes overview |

so I tried this and id didn't work.

```
SELECT groupid,
if(sessnum=1,notes,"") as S1,
if(sessnum=2,notes,"") as S2,
if(sessnum=3,notes,"") as S3,
if(sessnum=4,notes,"") as S4,
if(sessnum=5,notes,"") as S5,
if(sessnum=6,notes,"") as S6,
if(sessnum=7,notes,"") as S7,
if(sessnum=8,notes,"") as S8,
if(sessnum=9,notes,"") as S9,
if(sessnum=10,notes,"") as S10,
if(sessnum=0,notes,"") as OVER
FROM `grpnotes`
group by groupid
```

Instead it gives me this:

| groupid | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 | S6 | S7 | S8 | S9 | S10 | OVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QRgy6FhjgDVIPDt | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | notes overview |

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Add `MAX()` around each of your `if(...)` statements, and see if that helps (ie `MAX(if(sessnum=1,notes,"")) as S1,` etc)

Comment: Thank You Rob.  That absolutely fixed the problem!